# BusyIndicator is not visible?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I am doing some operation like reading a csv file and converting to an object. Its all working fine except that the BusyIndicator is not visible even though busyindicator.Isbusy = true;

Everything is running on the Main Thread, So  I guess when I read the file, the UI or Main thread might be busy as a result its not visible.

Code:

```
    private void ImportData(Dictionary<string, ImportFieldMap> mappedItems)
    {

        var fileBytes = fileBrowseCtrl.FileBytes;
        var getDelimiter = string.IsNullOrEmpty(txeSeperator.Text) ? UtilFunctions.GetDefaultDeLimiter() : txeSeperator.Text.ToCharArray()[0];
        if (fileBytes == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Uniconta.ClientTools.Localization.lookup("NoFilesSelected"), Uniconta.ClientTools.Localization.lookup("Error"), MessageBoxButton.OK);
            return;
        }
        Encoding Coding = Encoding.Unicode;
        if (ANSICodePage.IsUTF8(fileBytes))
            Coding = Encoding.UTF8;
        else if (ANSICodePage.IsANSI(fileBytes))
        {
            fileBytes = ANSICodePage.Convert2Unicode(fileBytes);
            Coding = Encoding.Unicode;
        }

        try
        {
            busyIndicator.IsBusy = true;
            CSVHelper csvData;
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(fileBytes), Coding, true))
            {
                csvData = CSVHelper.Load(reader, getDelimiter);
            }
            //Converting to UnicontaObject Code...
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Uniconta.ClientTools.Localization.lookup("InvalidFileFormat"), Uniconta.ClientTools.Localization.lookup("Error"), MessageBoxButton.OK);
            fileBrowseCtrl.ResetControl();
        }
        finally
        {
            busyIndicator.IsBusy = false;
        }
    }
```

Is there a way I can seperately run on different threads so that when the function is called the UI displays the busyIndicator and in the background the operation like reading csv and converting to object happens

I have tried using the BackgroundWorkerThread but is an asynhrocnous so is there any other way achieving this?

regards

Comment: `BackgroundWorker` suits your requirement. However, I did not get what do you mean by ---but is an asynhrocnous so is there any other way achieving. You can subscribe to DoWork and RunWorkCompletedEvent. Read and Load the CSV data in DoWork Handler and return that result in RunWorkCompletedEvent handler. Also, set busyIndicator.IsBusy = false in RunWorkCompletedEvent handler.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Multihreading**

1.1 BackgroungWorker is fine.

1.2. Another option is to use the `Dispatcher`

Every WPF component has a `Dispatcher` you can use to get back on the GUI thread :

```C#
// Get the dispatcher on the Gui thread
Dispatcher dispatcher = window.Dispatcher;

// use it on the worker thread to get back to GUI thread
dispatcher.Invoke( 
  () =>{
    busyIndicator.IsBusy = true;
);
```

**2. Updating the GUI**

The reason why you ve got not change in the GUI, may be that that your GUI property doesn't raise any event.

```C#
public bool IsBusy{
    get{ return isBusy; }
    set{ 
       isBusy = value;
       FirePropertyChange();
    }
}
```

And `INotifyPropertyChanged` should be implemented on the class hoding the IsBusy property:

```
public class User : IDataErrorInfo, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private void OnNotifyPropertyChange([CallerMemberName]string propName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

Regards